# PMF given by Poisson

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I have a question for my probability class that I am struggling with. It asks to find F(2), meaning find the probability that $$f_Y(k\le2)$$ given:
$$f_Y(k) = \begin{cases}
\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{k}}{k!} & k = 0,1,2,...\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
I know that this is a Poisson distribution but I am not sure what values to use for λ and k. My best guess would be 2 and 1, however I am sure that is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$F(2)=f(y \leq 2)=e^{-\lambda}[1+\lambda+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}]$$

to have a numerical value of this probability you need more information about $\lambda$, i.e. more information about the mean of your rv

Comment: All I am given is that k is a random variable